# Python how to convert a value with shape (1000L, 1L) to the value of the shape (1000L,)

Tags: python, numpy

I has a variable with a shape of (1000L, 1L), but the structure causes some errors for subsequent analysis. It needs to be converted to the one with the shape (1000L,). Let me be more specific.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([[1],[2],[3]])
```

I want to convert b to a. Is there any quick way to do that?

Comment: So do you mean you want a tuple with `None` as the second value? I don't think it's clear what `(1000L,)` means.

Comment: The data type is uint8, I don't need to change the type

Comment: @JennerFelton: `(1000L,)` is the syntax for a 1-element tuple whose one element is `1000L` (and `1000L` is a Python 2 `long` with value 1000). Type it into Python if you want to try it.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of ways you could do that, such as indexing:

```
a = b[:, 0]
```

raveling:

```
a = numpy.ravel(b)
```

or reshaping:

```
a = numpy.reshape(b, (-1,))
```

Comment: and don't forget b.squeeze()